# Stablecoins on EOS, are there any?

Tags: tokens, ethereum

Are there any reputable Stablecoin type projects being built on EOS like how Ethereum has USDC by coinbase? Or even a EOS tether?

Answer (score 2):

The only (somehow) regulated one for now I know is CarbonUSD: https://www.carbon.money/ .

There is another USDT-pegged&backed EOS stable coin EUSD (https://eosstablecoin.com/), though I'm not sure about its trustworthiness. It's listed in Newdex, Chaince, etc.

Comment: its not on any exchange...

Comment: @Patoshiパトシ Then you may have a look at EUSD.

Comment: thats not on any exchange neither.

Comment: @PatoshiパトシYou are wrong. EUSD is on Newdex (https://newdex.io/trade/eosio.token-eos-eusd) at least.

Comment: Not very stable if its worth $3.50 for 1 EUSD. I guess we'll just have to wait it out...

Comment: @PatoshiパトシNo you misunderstood. $3.50 is the price of EOS. The link is to EOS/EUSD market.